# C# odbc connection to sql creating tables but dont see in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, odbc

I want to create tables in SQL Server in my program. The code compiles and everything seems to be ok, but after I close it the tables don't appear in the SQL Server database.

EDITED

Please help here is the code and the connection string:

```
connectionString = "Driver={Sql Server}; Server=baxu\\sqlexpress; Database = baza1;" + $"UID ={ username };PWD={ password };";
```

---

Code:

```
try
{
    using (OdbcCommand comm = new OdbcCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = cnn;
        comm.CommandText = cmdString;
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
}
```

Comment: Why on earth are you using **ODBC** to connect to SQL Server? That's a technology that's about twice dead already and superseeded by later technologies.... any particular reason you're not using the **native SQL Client** code base - `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` etc. ??

Comment: If you `Show()`ed the exception message instead of the literal string "ex.Message" you would probably see that you did not `Open()` the connection.

Comment: My boss told me to do so in case that the program would be working with an old sql server version. He said that sql native client could read the data from older software wrongly. What do you think about it? If I just change it to native it will work fine?

Comment: Your missing .Open()

Comment: It should be there, if there are no errors, the table should be in the baxu\\sqlexpress server as baza1.Tablename. Check the baza1 schema. Dont confuse it with the default dbo. schema.

Comment: Yes there is unnecessary "" in catch but it doesnt pop up anyways

Comment: these are different parts of code,sorry i pasted it so it looked like i dont open connection,i do it before i try to make tables

Comment: @Kosu, ODBC is alive and well but not appropriate to access SQL Server from managed .NET code. The SqlClient managed provider should always be used. ODBC and OLE DB in ADO.NET is intended to be used only for DBMS products that don't have a managed .NET provider.

Comment: @Kosu, post a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: ok because it works fine with Sql native connection I will just use thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

This here should work for you:

> NB: If you dont use trusted connection - Then look at the different connectionstrings [here](https://www.dofactory.com/reference/connection-strings):

```
var conn = new OdbcConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString =
                          @"Driver={SQL Server};" +
                         @"Server=EGC25199\SQL2016;" +
                          @"DataBase=LegOgSpass;" +
                          @"Trusted_Connection=Yes;";


            try
            {
                string cmdString = "CREATE TABLE dbo.odbctable (Wartosc int, Czas datetime)";                                         
                conn.Open();

                using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(cmdString, conn))
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help. I noticed you used an unassigned `name` in the `create` command.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;
   class CommandOdbcExample{

      static void Main() {
     OdbcConnection comm = new OdbcConnection(@"DSN=MyOdbcdDB");
     OdbcCommand nonqueryCommand = comm.CreateCommand();

         try {
            comm.Open();

            nonqueryCommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE MyTable (Wartosc  int, Czas  datetime)";
            Console.WriteLine(nonqueryCommand.CommandText);
            nonqueryCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();




         } 
         catch (OdbcException ex) 
         {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
         }
         finally 
         {  
            comm.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection Closed.");
         }
      }
   }
```